# Unfold a set of edges

Tags: edges

I have a long curve of 425 vertices where there is two round parts :

[image]

I would like to unfold this curve to have a straight line where all edges length are the same than the initial curve.

Thanks !

Comment: ...it could work adding an armature of 425 bones, each snapped to move single segments... :D I can't think of any other way...

Answer (score 1):

I have created a script to do it.
There is probably a native way so I do not accept my own answer.

Here is the script :

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
mesh = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

previous = 0
current = bm.verts[399] #index of one of the two extremity

points = [0]

flag = False
while flag is False:
    flag = True
    for edge in current.link_edges:
        nei = edge.other_vert(current)
        if nei is not previous:
            previous = current
            current = nei
            flag = False
            len = (previous.co-current.co).length
            points.append(points[-1]+len)
            break

for v in points:
    bm.verts.new((v,0,0))

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

Comment: Nice one.  For ends, could look for verts that have only one link edge and put them in a list. `[v for v in bm.verts if len(v.link_edges) == 1]` Pop one and walk edges till you find the other end, pop the end and repeat till ends list is empty.  Could also use [`BMEdge.calc_length()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMEdge.calc_length).